# Do some phones not print messages to Logcat in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I'm new to Android Studio and have been attempting to print messages using Log.d() for an assignment. Because my PC doesn't support virtualization, I've been using my phone the LeEco Le Pro3 to run my apps, but recently I've noticed that the Log.d() messages aren't appearing (while others are). I've been searching around a lot for why, and no fixes seem to work. My Android Studio is up to date, and my PC seems fine. I did see a small post about how some manufactures don't print messages to Android Studio, and so I'm wondering if that's true and that LeEco is one of them.

Edit: upon trying it on a separate laptop that allows virtualization, the virtual phone (I arbitrarily chose a Pixel phone) allows debug level messages to show in Logcat. Though connecting my phone to this laptop still doesn't print debug messages.

Answer (score 0):

Emulators or Real devices do not print **`Log`** messages. What I mean to say is these **`log messages`** do not go in the **`console`**, but rather to the **`LogCat`**. You can find the **`LogCat`** window as shown below in the android studio:

[image]

If you are looking to print messages to **`console`**, rather use:

```
System.out.println()
```

Comment: I guess my question wasn't phrased quite right. I am already looking at my Logcat window and I want D/ (debug) messages to appear when running my app on my phone (the LeEco).
And due to class assignments, I need debug messages instead of println() which appear as I/ (info) messages.